# iOS 13 no longer supports WebSQL on Chrome. Is there a way to enable back Web SQL on the Chrome browser app?

Tags: web-sql, chrome-ios

Unable to open a web application that uses "Web SQL API" on Chrome browser app (iOS 13). Although the new iOS 13 no longer supports WebSQL (bot Safari and Chrome), Safari has a workaround (Setting->Safari->Advanced->Experimental features) that enables back the Web SQL, but what about on Chrome?

I tried to find some option in the Chrome hidden features but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All browsers on iOS are using safari under the hood so there is no way you can enable it in Chrome. The WebSQL can only be enabled for Safari as the browser. It cannot be enabled for Safari webview which is used for "fullscreen" apps or other browsers.